# directive - scope not binding to templateurl, angularjs

Tags: angularjs

When referencing a controller in my directive. the template is not rendered correctly.
 `$scope.name = "James".`
Instead, the template is displaying "{{name}}" and thus not binding to the scope.
How can I make my template display the name? I want to refer to controllers in my directive, I don't want to define a controller within my directive.

Error I'm getting: Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string

**template html**

```
<div id="room-availability-widget">

  {{name}}
 </div>
```

**directive**

```
 app.directive("roomAvailability", ["backEndServerUrl", "hubName", function (serverUrl, hubName) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'Widgets/RoomAvailability/Template.html',
        scope: {},
        controller: 'clientHandlers'
    }
}]);
```

**Controller**

```
 app.controller('clientHandlers', ["$scope", function clientHandlers($scope)       
{

    $scope.name = "James";
}])
```

**Index view**

```
 <room-availability></room-availability>
```

**update**
Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/mVMN65bx7OT70OwSOllW?p=preview

Comment: Post a complete example reproducing the prolem on Plunkr. And post the complete error stack trace. Tell us which line of code code it refers to. Also, what's the poirn of injecting serverUrl and hubName in the directive, since it doesn't use them at all?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, just your Plunker is not well organized. Check this one: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KFmwUE13luVSIG3hm9Cr?p=preview).

Your angular import line:

```
<script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="2.0.0-alpha.31" src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.31/angular.js"></script>
```

is not working. Because `https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.31/angular.js` is not there. What I did to your plunker:

1. I changed to some 1.x version.
2. Remove unknown providers `serverUrl, hubName`
3. Change the template url from `Widgets/RoomAvailability/Template.html` to `Template.html`.

Advice: Check errors on the console whenever your code fails.

Answer (score -1):

You can resolve this issue in multiple ways, but I could think of below for now

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module("RoomAvailabilityWidget", [])
    
app.directive("roomAvailability", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E/A',
        templateUrl: 'Template.html',
        scope: {name: '@'},
        controller : function( $scope ){
            //$scope.selectedFile = "No files selected";
           $scope.name = 'james'
        }
    }
});
```

Plunker to http://plnkr.co/edit/xnpq83akxbDF8m6oy1Bj?p=preview

Hope this helps

Comment: If the controller value is a name, Angular will find the controller for you.